# Why does [ -f ${x} ] evaluate to true for empty x in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Lets have standard file checking code in Bash:

```
f=$1

if [ ! -f "${f}" ];then
    echo "Does not exit"
fi
```

Why, when I remove weak quoting like this: `if [ ! -f ${f} ]` does this evaluate to `true` but `if [ ! -f "" ]`  to `false` ?

Comment: Without quotes it is effectively `if [ -f ]; then ...`

Comment: Which is equal to `if [ -n "-f" ]`

Comment: @123 Any idea why `[[` behaves differently?

Comment: @JoshLee Technically, `-f` doesn't take an argument. The behavior of `test`/`[` is strictly defined by the number of arguments it receives, so there is a very big difference between `test -f` and `test -f <something>`. Only in the second case is `-f` interpreted as an operator.

Comment: @JoshLee `[[` is a special built-in command that is not evaluated by the normal rules for ordinary commands.

Comment: (well, "strictly defined" except in cases with `-o`, `-a`, or a pair consisting of `(` and `)`, and enough arguments to make any of those meaningful; *not* having a strict definition of the corner cases in those uses has a great deal to do with why more-than-four-argument uses are flagged obsolescent).

Answer (score 4):

There are several rules you must understand to make sense of POSIX shell and the `test` command.

1. Unquoted parameter expansions are subject to word-splitting; quoted parameter expansions are not.

   <sup>(Note: I say POSIX shell above because `zsh` is a prominent example of a shell that does *not* subject unquoted parameter expansions to word-splitting by default. `bash` does conform to the POSIX specification on this point.)</sup>
2. The behavior of the `test` command is defined by the number of arguments it receives. Only after the argument count is determined can you start to interpret what the arguments mean.
3. `test` can also be spelled `[`, in which case the final argument *must* be `]`, but that argument is otherwise ignored for the purposes of determining how many arguments are passed to `[`. That is, `[ -f "$f" ]` and `test -f "$f"` behave identically.
4. If the first argument of the `test` command is `!`, then it is ignored for the purposes of counting and evaluating the remaining arguments, but the result of the evaluation is negated.

---

Now, to your question. `[ ! -f $f ]` is first subjected to parameter expansion. By point 1 above, `$f` when unquoted expands to *nothing*; after word-splitting occurs, there is no non-empty string left to form a word. This means the shell sees `[ ! -f ]` to be evaluated. This is recognized as the `test` command receiving two arguments, `!` and `-f`. By point 4, this means that the one-argument expression `-f` is evaluated, which is done by testing if the string is empty or not. `-f` is not an empty string, so `test` would succeed, but the `!` inverts it, so `test` ultimately fails.

If `$f` *were* quoted, then parameter expansion produces `[ ! -f "" ]`; there is an explicit empty string passed to `test`. After setting aside `!` and `]`, we are left with a *two*-argument call to `test`. With two arguments, the first must be a recognized unary operator, and the second is treated as an argument to the first. Now, `-f` is an operator that tests if its argument names an existing regular file. The empty string is not a valid file name, so there can be no such regular file; the test would fail, with `!` inverting that so that the call to `test` succeeds.